# Как и куда лучше записывать данные пользователя?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Я создаю бота - ежедневник. Пользователи будут писать боту свой текст, он должен их куда-то записать. Я новичок и не понимаю пока, куда записывать эти данные и важно, чтобы данные были прикреплены к конкретному пользователю.

Comment: Однозначно, в базу данных. Там всё это можно реализовать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для *прикрепления* к пользователю необходим некий идентификатор пользователя, который нужно создавать. Далее этот идентификатор и введённый текст можно записывать в базу данных.